# Omit object key which has empty string in array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do I simplify the array below

```
[ { uuid: '',
    quantity: 3,
    procurement_detail_uuid: '',
    distribution_officer_uuid: '',
    substore_uuid: '2343423443423' },
  { uuid: '',
    quantity: 3,
    procurement_detail_uuid: '',
    distribution_officer_uuid: '',
    substore_uuid: '676767' } ]
```

to

```
[ { quantity: 3,
    substore_uuid: '2343423443423' },
  { quantity: 3,
    substore_uuid: '676767' } ]
```

What is the fastest way reduce and filter those key?

Comment: please add a *not-so-fast* version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array, [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) each object's [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and take only non empty values:

```js
const data = [{"uuid":"","quantity":3,"procurement_detail_uuid":"","distribution_officer_uuid":"","substore_uuid":"2343423443423"},{"uuid":"","quantity":3,"procurement_detail_uuid":"","distribution_officer_uuid":"","substore_uuid":"676767"}];

const result = data.map((o) => Object.keys(o)
  .reduce((r, k) => o[k] !== '' ? Object.assign(r, { [k]: o[k] }) : r, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `map` followed by `forEach` and finally `delete`

```
arr = arr.map( function(item){ 
   Object.keys( item ).forEach( function(key){ 
      if ( item[key] == '' )
      { 
         delete item[key] 
      } 
    }); 
    return item; 
})
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [ { uuid: '', quantity: 3, procurement_detail_uuid: '',     distribution_officer_uuid: '', substore_uuid: '2343423443423' },
  { uuid: '',  quantity: 3, procurement_detail_uuid: '',    distribution_officer_uuid: '', substore_uuid: '676767' } ];
  
arr = arr.map( function(item){ Object.keys( item ).forEach( function(key){ if ( item[key] == '' ){ delete item[key] } } ); return item; } )

console.log(arr);
```